# Extract number from first line of a file in linux

Tags: linux, bash

I have a file which has contents like the below

```
SPEC.2.ATTRID=REVISION&
SPEC.2.VALUE=5&
SPEC.3.ATTRID=NUM&
SPEC.3.VALUE=VS&
```

I am using the below command to extract only the numbers from the first line. Is this way efficient or you guys think of an alternate way ?

```
cat ticketspecdata | tr -d " " | tr -s "[:alpha:]" "~" | tr -d "[=.=]" | cut -d "~" -f2
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [grep](/questions/tagged/grep) :

```
$ grep -om1 '[0-9]\+' file
2
```

Answer (score 1):

Or

```
head -n1 file | tr -cd '[:digit:]'
```

You may also want to read about UUOC:

- http://porkmail.org/era/unix/award.html

Comment: you have to use `head -n1 file | tr -cd '[:digit:]'`